# Error compiling OpenSSL for Win32

Tags: windows, visual-c++, winapi, openssl, nmake

I get the following  error when trying to build OpenSSL on Win32:

> `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\errno.h(92) : error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated`
>   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\errno.h(92) : warning C4005: 'EADDRINUSE' : macro redefinition`
>   `tmp32\e_os.h(153) : see previous definition of 'EADDRINUSE'`
>   `NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
>   Stop.`

I've followed the instructions in INSTALL.W32 to the letter. I configured with the no-asm flag. I am using Visual Studio Express 2010 C++.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this a bug in OpenSSL 1.0.0. I downloaded the 1.0.0a source and it is compiling fine.

Comment: Apparently VS2010 includes updated header files that define `EADDRINUSE` which previously hadn't been.