# Error compiling OpenSSL-0.9.7 for Win32

Tags: openssl

I'm installing OpenSSL openssl-0.9.7 on Win32 from the VC++ environment prompt.
When I run the following command:

> nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak

I get following results

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Building OpenSSL
        copy nul+ .\crypto\buildinf.h tmp32dll\buildinf.h
nul
.\crypto\buildinf.h
        1 file(s) copied.
        cl /Fotmp32dll\cryptlib.obj  -Iinc32 -Itmp32dll /MD /W3 /WX /G5 /Ox /O2
/Ob2 /Gs0 /GF /Gy /nologo -DOPENSSL_SYSNAME_WIN32 -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DL_ENDI
AN -DDSO_WIN32 -DBN_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DSHA1_ASM -DRMD160_ASM /Fdout32dll -DOPENSSL_
NO_KRB5 -D_WINDLL  -DOPENSSL_BUILD_SHLIBCRYPTO -c .\crypto\cryptlib.c
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/G5'
cryptlib.c
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\errno.h(92) : error C22
20: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\errno.h(92) : warning C
4005: 'EADDRINUSE' : macro redefinition
        tmp32dll\e_os.h(156) : see previous definition of 'EADDRINUSE'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BI
N\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

I am using visual Studio 2010. What is the problem and how it can be solved?

Comment: Take a look at [this ticket](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=2261&user=guest&pass=guest) and also possible duplicate of [Error compiling OpenSSL for Win32](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242386/error-compiling-openssl-for-win32) (look at the answer there).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in the .txt file where building steps are given? I have worked with this. It should work.